# Simple connected semi-simple group

Tags: algebraic-groups

Here is a question form springer's book Linear Algebraic Groups, 8.4.6(6)

> Let $G$ be semi-simple and simple-connected, $P$ a parabolic subgroup
>   of $G$ with Levi group $L$, Prove the commutator group $(L,L)$ is
>   semi-simple and simple-connected.

I do not know how to deal with the simple-connected, please help.